# Declaring an active workbook variable Excel Vba

Tags: excel, vba, variables

(Excel VBA)

How would i declare an active workbook variable. or a workbook variable in general.

I have a program flipping back and forth between 2 excel workbooks, and currently we have it just reopen that workbook. But can I just declare it as a variable so i can reference it without re-opening. It would make my life a lot easier .

Thanks in advance!

My current example:

```
Dim xlsMatrixUp As String
fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls")
xlsMatrixUp = fileToOpen
Workbooks.Open xlsMatrixUp
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(4).Activate 'Grabs matrix file

'Goes back to sheet with macro
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(4).Activate
    ActiveSheet.range("A1").Interior.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
'This is off a working if statement 
Workbooks.Open xlsMatrixUp
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(4).Activate`
'Returns to matrix and repeats. Any suggestions?
```

Comment: you don't usually need to switch between them-just manipulate ranges directly `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(4).range("A1").Interior.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)` for instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim wB as Workbook
Set wB = Workbooks.Open(xlsMatrixUp)
```

then you can refer to it as `wB.worksheets(4).Activate` for example

Comment: You sir, deserve a pat on the back

Comment: You're very welcome. Obviously, you can also declare a worksheet and refer to it right away.
`Set wS = wB.Worksheets(4)` and then refer to it directly as `wS.Range("A1")`